# Error calling channel.Create on appengine with GO

Tags: google-app-engine, go, channel-api

I am using the sample code in the [Channel Api Go Reference](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/go/channel/overview.html#Example_Tic_Tac_Toe_Application). When I run, I got the following error:

channel.Create:: Call error 1: call /channel.CreateChannel is not registered

I could not find any reference to it. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/cetKWCkoHfg it's a known error in AppEngine runtime: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5279